# virtual base class with public/private constructor Behavior difference

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constructor

if i run this code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Final;

class MakeFinal{
public:
friend class Final;
MakeFinal(){cout<<"makefinal\n";}
};

class Final: public virtual MakeFinal{
public:
 Final(){cout<<"Final\n";}
};

 class Derived:public Final{
public:
  Derived(){cout<<"Derived\n";}
};


int main(){
//Final f;
Derived d;
return 0;
}
```

Output is :

makefinal
Final
Derived

But if i make MakeFinal() constructor private , compiler shows error message. What  is this different constructor call hierarchy based on ?

Comment: If a base class constructor is private then nothing other than a friend class (or the class itself) can make one, including via inheritance.

Comment: Horrible formatting aside, why are you using virtual inheritance in the first place in this code? Do you understand what problems virtual inheritance helps solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to:

[C++ FAQs - virtual inheritance constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-ctors.html)
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-ctors.html

Because of the fact that "Initialization list of most-derived-class's ctor directly invokes the virtual base class's ctor. ", your most derived needs to invoke the constructor of the virtual base directly. Therefore, for what you want to do you'd need to make the most derived class a friend too...

Furthermore, it seems that you don't understand virtual inheritance correctly. Refer to [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-where.html) to understand the purpose and proper use of virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If your class `A` have private constructor, you cannot create object `a` of this class like that ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648602/private-constructor)):

```
A a;
```

When an object `b` of class `B` that derives from `A` is created, base class constructor must also be called. If it is private, it cannot be called and the derived object cannot be created.