# Subclass with private Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, private, private-constructor

I've a simple question.
Can a subclass have a private constructor (i.e. for singleton implementation) in C++?

```
class MySubClass : public MySuperClass {
public:
   // etc.
private:
    MySubClass();
    static MySubClass* _instance;
};
```

Is this example right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of making constructor private in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062560/what-is-the-use-of-making-constructor-private-in-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how singletons are implemented in C++. The class also usually has a `static` method through which you can return an instance.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My doubt is about inheritance. Thank you so much.

Comment: Typically they also have their copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor declared private as well. Most of the Singletons in C++ I've seen only return a reference or a pointer to the class.