# Can we print the address of object of class in C++?

Tags: c++

How can we Print the address of object of class in the member function of that class in C++?

```
class A
{
     int x;
   private:
     A(){x=2;}
}
int main()
{
   A B;
   return 0;
}
```

How to print the address of B in member function or in main().

Comment: Note that your code throws a compile error since your constructor is private. The question is still valid with a public constructor.

Answer (score 12):

Just add

```
#include <iostream>
```

at the top of the file and the following line at the bottom of `main`:

```
std::cout << &B << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside main:

```
std::cout << &B << std::endl;
```

Inside member function:

```
A () {
    x=2;
    //this is a pointer to the this-object
    std::cout << this << std::endl;
}
```

Don't forget to include `<iostream>` for output.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way:
`printf("%p", &B);`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
std::cout << &B;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the address of an object, use the address-of operator `&`.

Answer (score 2):

With C++20 you can use [std::to_address](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A{};

int main()
{
    A B;
    std::cout << std::to_address(&B) << '\n'
}
```

Which has the advantage of being able to accept raw pointers, smart pointers, iterators, and pointer-like objects. Making it useful for cases that require generic code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
cout << &B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
     public:
     A(){
      cout<<this<<endl;
     }
};

int main()
{
   A* a = new A();
   cout<<a<<endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the memory address you need to convert B to a pointer when printing. So

```
cout << &B << endl;
```

The ampersand, when used before a variable, calls the pointer of the variable instead of the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in THAT specific class you have defined. You can't. Your constructor is private and you forgot a semi-colon at the end of your class definition, therefore, your code won't compile.

Ignoring these issues to display the pointer of an object in `main` you can use

```
std::cout << &B;
```

Or in a member function you can use

```
std::cout << this;
```

(Don't forget to include `iostream`)

Answer (score 0):

this line has to be add-cout<<"address is:"<<&B;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    class A
    {
     int x;

    };

  int main()
   {
   A B;
   cout<<"address is:"<<&B;
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are a lot of answers for your question already, but I don't know why none of them point that you have a private constructor for class A, and the way the object B is being instantiated should throw a compilation error.
At least, it did in my case. There is a whole lot of concepts around using private constructors, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2385764/3278350 gives a good idea.