# Static method class instantiation

Tags: c++, static-methods

How does a c++ line like this `Foo t3 = Foo::construct(true);` work when the default constructor is private? My assumption (which is obviously incorrect), is that the default constructor is called, followed my the assignment operator. That assumption must be incorrect because the default constructor is private, and cannot be called.

A concrete example:

```
class Foo {
private:
   Foo() {}
   bool bar;
public:
   Foo(bool t): bar(t) {}
   static Foo construct(bool t) {
      Foo temp; //calling private constructor;
      temp.bar = t;
      return temp;
   }
}
```

And a test method for instantiating this class looks like:

```
int main() {
   //Foo t1; //Not allowed, compile error, Foo() is private
   Foo t2(true); //Constructor, valid use
   Foo t3 = Foo::construct(true); //It works! Why?
   return 0;
}
```

What is really happening behind the scenes when `t3` is instantiated?

Comment: `Foo t3 = Foo::construct(true);` makes a copy(symantically).  What is wrong with that?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm actually going unsure if the copy constructor would be auto generated for this case, would it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ per 12.8 *If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly.*

Comment: @NathanOliver THX, as mentioned I was unsure if copy constructor and copy assignment operator would be auto generated for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Foo t3 = Foo::construct(true); //It works! Why?
```

Because this is not default initiliazation followed by assignment but [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

> 1) when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) of a
>   non-reference type T is declared with the initializer consisting of an
>   equals sign followed by an expression.

So according to this statement:

> If T is a class type and the cv-unqualified version of the type of
>   other is T or a class derived from T, the non-explicit constructors of
>   T are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution.
>   The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

and this:

> If other is an rvalue expression, move constructor will be selected by
>   overload resolution and called during copy-initialization. There is no
>   such term as move-initialization.

implicitly declared move constructor is used in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reference links! In my own words, a copy constructor is created by the compiler and used in the instantiation of t3.

Comment: Assuming c++11. Could move schematics be involved as well?

Comment: See updated answer, yes implicit move ctor is used in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Your line doesn't call the default constructor OR the copy-assignment operator.

It copy-constructs `t3` from the temporary object returned from `construct`.

Answer (score 0):

The static construct method belongs to the class and can access the private constructor - this is often used when implementing the factory pattern.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062560/what-is-the-use-of-making-constructor-private-in-a-class

Comment: The essence of the question is not if this pattern works. As you have proven, it does. But how t3 is constructed in my main method. What constructor is it using?