# Without private constructor we can access static member from one to other class?

Tags: c#

use of private constructor :
 it cant able to create instance,
 it cant be inherit,
 it contain only static data members

without  private constructor also i can able to access class with its static declaration and static data member when assign value like the below example

```
class Test
{        
    public static int x = 12;
    public static int method()
    {
        return 13;
    }
}
class Program
{
    int resut1 = Test.x;
    int resut2 = Test.method();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

so i have doubts as below
 why should go to private constructor
 what is the use of private constructor block
 is we cant do anything inside of private constructor block
 when it execute please explain clearly

thanks in advance

Comment: You can still call it from inside the class.

Comment: It seems like your `Test` class should be `static`.  I'm not clear where a private constructor comes into play in your example.

Comment: Already answered with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062560/what-is-the-use-of-making-constructor-private-in-a-class

Comment: i compared this with private constructor  what it create more.

Answer (score -1):

Private constructors are used to prevent creating instances of a class when there are no instance fields or methods, such as the Math class, or when a method is called to obtain an instance of a class. If all the methods in the class are static, consider making the complete class static. For more information see Static Classes and Static Class Members.

Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors

Answer (score -2):

A private constructor prevents the generic default constructor from being used.

The generic default constructor allows a class to be instantiated; while, a private constructor.

According to this [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors), they are generally used to prevent people from instantiating classes that only have static members/functions.

Comment: This is wrong, a private constructor does not completely prevent instantiating the class.  It just can't be used from outside the class itself.

Comment: @BenVoigt My bad, had some bad wording.